# VB .NET | App to App Interaction

Tags: vb.net, button, visible, interaction, invisible

I want  to make a test for my application. I'm using VB.Net and Visual Studio.
How can i make this example:
App1 has a button but this button is invisible.
If you open App2 after App1, App1's button will be visible. But how can i do that. I want to use only VB.Net. Thank you very much!

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34073/Inter-Process-Communication-IPC-Introduction-and-S I suggest you try this.

Comment: please provide some code which you had tried already, so we can put some effort on it.

Comment: Some code will be helpful

Answer (score -1):

Shared memory, [memory mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files), [pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx) or [sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397809(v=vs.90).aspx) can communicate between processes.